# iWork Numbers increase column size for sum

Tags: iwork, numbers

If I have columns that sum at the bottom, how can I have the sum function automatically include a newly inserted row.

```
    a
  +---+
1 | 1 |
2 | 1 |
3 | 1 |
4 | 1 |
  +---+
  |=sum(a1:a4)|
```

Then when I add row 5 the sum function should be

```
=sum(a1:a5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is embedded and its default behaviour. Of course if adding a row will be done using this option:

[image]

Comment: The function will only be updated when a row was inserted into the middle between a1 and a4, but it does not work when I add a row after a4.

Comment: Number '09 does, I've checked it twice.

Comment: Was the answer useful?

Comment: It does work. I have to add the row below the last row in the group. I was attempted to add a new row above the sum function.

Comment: I edited your answer to be more correct. Thank you.